# tikz: resize an equation inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, resize

I want to resize the equation embedded in a node of tikzpicture. `\resizebox` works, but there are always two errors I couldn't get rid of.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (5, 1.7) [text width=5cm] {
        \resizebox{2.5\hsize}{!}{
            \begin{equation*}
                \begin{matrix}
                    \textcolor{green}{n_1}   \\
                    \textcolor{green}{n_2}   \\
                    \textcolor{green}{n_3}   \\
                    \textcolor{green}{n_4}   \\
                    \textcolor{green}{n_5}   \\
                    \textcolor{blue}{n_6}   \\
                    \textcolor{orange}{n_7}   \\
                    \textcolor{orange}{n_8}   \\
                    \textcolor{orange}{n_9}
                \end{matrix}
                \begin{bmatrix}
                    e_5 & 0 & 0 \\
                    e_6 & 0 & 0 \\
                    e_7 & 0 & 0 \\
                    e_8 & 0 & 0 \\
                    e_2 & 0 & 0 \\
                    0 & e_1 & e_2 \\
                    e_1 & e_3 & e_4 \\
                    e_3 & e_5 & e_6 \\
                    e_4 & e_7 & e_8 
                \end{bmatrix}
            \end{equation*}
        }};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Errors:
[image]

I tried to wrap all math notations e.g. `n_1` `n_2` with `$$`, but it won't work. How to correctly resize equations inside a tikzpicture?

**EDIT:** tried to directly add scale=2 into `[]` as the comment suggested, this worked but the squared brackets became segments:

[image][image]

Comment: You could just `scale=2.5` as an option to the node? Using `\resizebox` doesn't seem necessary unless you're trying to do something very specific. (The latter won't scale the `inner sep`s.) With a set text width, `equation*` should work but you can always just use `$\displaystyle … $` which is more liberal in where you can use it.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel This worked, but I noticed that by scaling the equation, the squared brackets became several segments, please see my edit. How could we avoid this issue?

Comment: That's a visual glitch your viewer produces. With others it won't be noticeable. The brackets are made up of multiple segments. The scaling doesn't change it, it just highlights it. If that's a problem for you, you will need to find another way to construct these brackets.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, I see. It is not that obvious anyway, I can just ignore it.

Comment: There is also `[font=\large]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear how you test @ Qrrbrbirlbel, suggestion in his comment. The following variation of your MWE gives to my opinion a nice result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5, transform shape] 
\node   {$\begin{matrix}
    \textcolor{green}{n_1}   \\
    \textcolor{green}{n_2}   \\
    \textcolor{green}{n_3}   \\
    \textcolor{green}{n_4}   \\
    \textcolor{green}{n_5}   \\
    \textcolor{blue}{n_6}   \\
    \textcolor{orange}{n_7} \\
    \textcolor{orange}{n_8} \\
    \textcolor{orange}{n_9} \\
\end{matrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
    e_5 & 0 & 0     \\
    e_6 & 0 & 0     \\
    e_7 & 0 & 0     \\
    e_8 & 0 & 0     \\
    e_2 & 0 & 0     \\
    0 & e_1 & e_2   \\
    e_1 & e_3 & e_4 \\
    e_3 & e_5 & e_6 \\
    e_4 & e_7 & e_8 \\
\end{bmatrix} $
        }; % end of node
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I removed `\resizebox`, and added `scale` here: `\node at (5, 1.7) [text width=5cm, scale=0.95]`.  Seems that `scale` works for both the whole tikzpicture and the specific node.

Comment: @TianjianQin, scale works on whole picture as well as node option.  However, not completely on the same way. If at scaling picture you like to scale node too, you need to add option `transform shape`. But why you think, that you need to define `text width`? It is a bit unclear what you after.

Comment: If I remove `text width`, then there will be errors if I want to put `equation` inside a node, not sure why

Comment: @TianjianQin, please examine my answer. It works fine without use of `textwidth`.

Comment: I see, replacing `equation` by `$$` works. Thanks for the notice

Comment: @TianjianQin, I use single `$`, i.e. in-text math, not `$$` for display math (it is TeX notation, not recommended) . You  my use `$\displaystyle  ... $`, if you like to have display size symbols.